# How to Export and Import sharepoint subsite documnet library in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Please help me, for this i'm using power shell command as

```
Export-SPWeb  "http://iicss89:5555" -itemurl "/HelpFiles" -path "c:\helpdocument.cmp" -IncludeVersions All
```

it is working for main site document library properly but for subsite it is not working.
 for subsite i used below command but it shows error

```
 Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://iicss89:5555/Physics" -itemurl "/HelpFiles" -path "c:\helpphydocument.cmp" -IncludeVersions All
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemUrl parameter must be server relative url. You need to remove the leading slash.

So it should be like this;

> -itemurl "HelpFiles"